# Azure AD App Registration: How AAD behaves differently with Web and SPA redirect URIs

Tags: azure-active-directory

When I register an AAD application, I can choose between Web and SPA redirect URIs:

[image]

How exactly AAD behaves differently with each of the URIs?
What are the differences between Web and SPA URIs?

**Update #1**

Follow up to @Hari Krishna response:

> By configuring your redirect URI using the Single-page application
> tile in the Add a platform pane, your application registration is
> configured to support the authorization code flow with PKCE and CORS.

Question:

There seems to be a duplicate of configuration here below. Is this an overlap to define if an application can support SPA's implicit flow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration) which will help.

> By configuring your redirect URI using the **Single-page
> application** tile in the Add a platform pane, your application
> registration is configured to support the authorization code flow with
> PKCE and CORS.

Comment: Thank you for help. I updated my question. Would you be able to clarify?

Comment: Yes, By checking the two options(Access token ,Id token) helps to enable implicit grant flow.Also, Application's will support SPA without implicit flow .

Comment: For example, you can use **Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)**

Comment: Why implict flow can be configured in two diffrent way?

Comment: Because implicit flow  require id token to  authenticate and other flows does not require id token to authenticate.